# System Config Tab Not Showing CE 1.8

Tags: configuration, ce-1.8.0.0, system.xml

I'm trying to add a simple tab to the system configuration in Magento CE 1.8.0.0. It's not showing at all with my code, as follows:

**File: app/code/community/Test/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <test_module translate="title" module="test_module">
                                        <title>Test Tabs Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>999</sort_order>
                                    </test_module>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**File: app/code/community/Test/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <test_module>
                <class>Test_Module_Helper</class>
            </test_module>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**File: app/code/community/Test/Module/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <test_module translate="label" module="test_module">
            <label>Test Module</label>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        </test_module>
    </tabs>
</config>
```

**File: app/code/community/Test/Module/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Test_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{}
```

**File: app/etc/modules/Test_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Test_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I'm expecting an empty tab in the admin's system configuration section, but nothing shows at all. I have emptied the cache and re-logged several times. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tab does not appear if you don't have sections in it (most probably).
Add a section with at least a group and a field in it.
**[EDIT]**
Here is my `system.xml` that worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <test_module translate="label" module="test_module">
            <label>Test Module</label>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
        </test_module>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <test_module translate="label" module="test_module">
            <label>Test</label>
            <tab>test_module</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <settings translate="label">
                    <label>Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>
                </settings>
            </groups>
        </test_module>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Thx Marius, tried that but still nothing. I have this same module (empty tab) working in CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Jongosi Did you try to log out and relogin?

Comment: Yes, many times :(

Comment: @Jongosi I've tested with you code and indeed the new tab does not appear. But, like I've said in my answer, If you add a section with a group and a field (at least) everything works great. If you say that your code worked with 1.7 (I've never tried and empty tab before) I can conclude that something changed in 1.8.

Comment: Thx Marius, could u please paste your sample section, group and field code in your answer - I can't get mine to work? Thanks!

Comment: @Jongosi I've added the code that worked for me

Comment: Thx Marius, I was missing `<show_in_default>1</show_in_default><show_in_website>1</show_in_website><show_in_store>1</show_in_store>` in my `fields` declaration all along. Thank you! Hopefully I never have to ask another Magento `xml` question!